# How to grep the following lines from a file?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, grep, regular-expression

I have a file which has the names of many files in a directory in the following format:

```
A20150824.0950-0955_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0945-0950_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0940-0945_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0935-0940_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0955-1000_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0000-0005_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0100-0105_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0105-0110_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0110-0115_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0115-0120_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0120-0125_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.1400-1405_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
```

The naming convention of the above files is `A<YYYYMMDD>.HHMM-HHMM_<city>_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob`.

These files are created for every 5 minute for all the hours each day such that, for every hour i get 12 files and for every day 12X24 files. I have generated a file which has got the names of all the 12x24 files and have a `while` loop in bash script where I am trying to do some processing per hour. I want to find a way by which I could create another file which contains the 12 files for each hour. For this, I am having a while outer loop which gives the hour value and inner minute loop which gives the minutes value. These files has the time information in their names. Ex:

```
A20150824.0950-0955_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
```

gives the information of 09-50 AM to 09-55 AM.

How do I use `grep` to extract the filenames from the file which contains all the 12X24 file names and put them in a separate file such that a new file contains the following file names:

```
A20150824.0900-0905_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0905-0910_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0910-0915_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
A20150824.0915-0920_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
.
.
.
A20150824.0955-1000_jambala_CcnActiveSessionCounterJob
```

I already have a variable `hour` which has the currently being processed hour information, I was trying to use the following but it doesn't work:

```
grep -E '.$hour' FILE_with_ALL_FILENAMES
```

where `.$hour` is targeted for `.09` in the above file name. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

```
hour=09
```

Just use that:

```
grep "\.$hour" file
```

With the single quotes in your example, the variable is not interpreted as variable. Therefore the pattern searches for `$hour`. Also the dot has to be escaped, else it would match any character.

Comment: Maybe also use `$(printf %02d $hour)` as it might be integer values without leading zeros. This would also allow using e.g. a simple `for` loop from 1 to 12.